# Printing columns and their headers using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to set titles for columns in my table and i used this code below:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "Name\tDescription\tType\tPrice";}
> {print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",$4,"\t",$NF;}
> END{print "Report Generated\n--------------";
> }' toys | column -s '/' -t
```

I have tried this code als, but I don't understand the sytax and the implementation there:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "Name\tDescription\tType\tPrice";}
> {printf "%-24s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$NF;}

> }' toys
```

The data and results that I want to have:

The table contains:

```
 Mini car Kids under 5 Wireless 2000
 Barbie   Kids 6 - 12  Electronic 3000
 Horse    Kids 6 -8    Electronic 4000
 Gitar    12 -16       ELectronic 45000
```

When I print the above command it gives me this output:

```
 Name    Description  Type   Price
 Mini car    Kids under 5     Wireless 2000
 Barbie    Kids 6 - 12  Electronic 3000
 Horse    Kids 6 -8    Electronic 4000
 Gitar    12 -16       ELectronic 45000
```

I want help to print them like that:

```
 Name        Description    Type       Price
 Mini car    Kids under 5   Wireless   2000
 Barbie      Kids 6 - 12    Electronic 3000
 Horse       Kids 6 -8      Electronic 4000
 Gitar       12 -16         ELectronic 45000
```

Comment: Use `printf()` with field width specifications.

Comment: Could you please republish my question. I am not getting the answer you provided.

Comment: What don't you understand? Show how you tried to apply the solution at the other question, and I'll reopen so we can correct it.

Comment: I have tried this code but it didn't work:

Comment: Where is `printf()` in your code?

Comment: `printf("%-10s %-15s %-10s %d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)`

Comment: This one worked thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that what the answer in the linked question says? Where did you get the idea to use `\t`?

Comment: Why do you understand it when I show it, but not in the other answer?

Comment: Because it didn't work I added \t

Comment: Because I am a beginner I don't understand these expressions and code syntax. Tha's why I ask for help when I get stuck.

Comment: I have been searching and trying but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a formatting operator for each value that's being printed. Since you're printing 4 columns, you need 4 formatting operators, to specify the width of each column.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf("%-10s %-15s %-10s %s\n", "Name", "Description", "Type", "Price");}
> {printf("%-10s %-15s %-10s %d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}
> }' toys 

`%s` is for printing strings, `%d` is for printing integers.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.